# Calling a component method from another component in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular, I have two components, the `app.component`, and `add.component`. In `app.component`, the template contains `li's`that get dynamic content from database(service). Now in `add.component`, I want to call the method from `app.component` so that the contents of `li's` inside `ul` will be updated after the user succesfully added data via form in `add.component`

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

import { CheatService } from './services/cheat.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
 })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  cheaterNames = [];
   constructor(public auth: AuthService, private cheatService: CheatService) 
  { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.getNames();
}
getNames() {// I want to call this method after the user submit the form in add.component
    this.cheatService.getNames().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.cheaterNames = res;
        },
        error => console.log(error)
    );
}
onAdded(ok) {
    if (ok === 'ok') {
        this.getNames();
        console.log('called');
    } else {
        console.log('not called');
    }
}
```

}

app.component.html

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column" *ngFor="let option of cheaterNames">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a [routerLink]="['/cheats',option]" class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ option }}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

add.component.ts

```
export class AddComponent implements OnInit {
isEditing = false;
public cheats = [];
public cheaterNames = [];
public selectedName = null;
addCheatForm: FormGroup;
title = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
code = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
description = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
name = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

@Output() onAdded = new EventEmitter();
constructor(private cheatService: CheatService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public toast: ToastComponent) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.addCheatForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        title: this.title,
        code: this.code,
        description: this.description,
        name: this.name
    });
    //this.getNames();
}
addCheat() {
    this.cheatService.addCheat(this.addCheatForm.value).subscribe(
        res => {
            const newCheat = res.json();
            this.cheats.push(newCheat);
            this.addCheatForm.reset();
            this.onAdded.emit('ok');//here I want to call getNames() from app.component, 
            this.toast.setMessage('item added successfully.', 'success');
        },
        error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

add.component.html

```
<app-toast [message]="toast.message"></app-toast>
<div class="card" *ngIf="!isEditing">
<h4 class="card-header">Add new cheat</h4>
<form [formGroup]="addCheatForm" (ngSubmit)="addCheat()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" formControlName="title" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="code" formControlName="code" placeholder="Code">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" formControlName="description" placeholder="Description">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="name" class="form-control" [ngModel] = "name" formControlName="name">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Name</option>
            <option  *ngFor="let type of cheaterNames" [value]="type">{{type}}</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" [ngModel] = "selectedName" formControlName="name" placeholder="Or add Name">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!addCheatForm.valid"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Add</button>
</form>
```

Any ideas on simplest approach? I also heard of a shared service, but still I am confused.

Comment: Just put the update code inside your success callback.
Can you explain precisely?

Comment: I want to call getNames() method from app.component in add.component addCheat() method if success

Comment: I think it alredy working via @output method , whats the issue then ?

Comment: @Vivek Doshi maybe I missed something, because its not working.

Comment: @IanAdem, is this function `onAdded(ok) {` beign called ?

Comment: How your are calling addCheat method in add component

Comment: @VivekDoshi unfortunately, not called.Show no errors too

Comment: Will you please post full app.component.html

Comment: @Runali inside in add.component.html, addCheat() method is called  <form [formGroup]="addCheatForm" (ngSubmit)="addCheat()">

Comment: @VivekDoshi I updated my question

Comment: Okay How you are calling add component from app component

Comment: @IanAdem, want you to post full app.component.html

Comment: code looks logical, have you put a break point at 'onAdded(ok)' and test it out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add `onAdded` on child component:

```
<AddComponent (onAdded)="onAdded($event)" />
```

Comment: add.component and add.component were not a parent/child type. Maybe I am wrong on how I created the components

Comment: Yes,Then it should be parent/child,@Output is build for that

Comment: So tha'ts the reason why its not working, maybe a shared service is needed because I don't want  this two component as of parent/child type

Comment: Yes then you should use shared service.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it

First I created a shared service

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
   private notify = new Subject<any>();
   /**
   * Observable string streams
   */
   notifyObservable$ = this.notify.asObservable();

    constructor() {}

    public notifyOther(data: any) {
       if (data) {
         this.notify.next(data);
       }
    }
}
```

Then i updated my app.component and add.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

import { CheatService } from './services/cheat.service';
import { CommonService } from './shared/common/common.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  cheaterNames = [];
  private subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(public auth: AuthService,
    private cheatService: CheatService,
    private commonService: CommonService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.getNames();
    this.subscription = this.commonService.notifyObservable$.subscribe((res) => {
        if (res.hasOwnProperty('option') && res.option === 'onSubmit') {
            console.log(res.value, 'called once');
            // perform your other action from here
            this.getNames();
        }
    });
}
getNames() {
    this.cheatService.getNames().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.cheaterNames = res;
        },
        error => console.log(error)
    );
 }
}
```

add.component

```
 export class AddComponent implements OnInit {
isEditing = false;
public cheats = [];
public cheaterNames = [];
public selectedName = null;
addCheatForm: FormGroup;
title = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
code = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
description = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
name = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

constructor(private cheatService: CheatService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public toast: ToastComponent,
    private commonService: CommonService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.addCheatForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        title: this.title,
        code: this.code,
        description: this.description,
        name: this.name
    });
    //this.getNames();
}
addCheat() {
    this.cheatService.addCheat(this.addCheatForm.value).subscribe(
        res => {
            const newCheat = res.json();
            this.cheats.push(newCheat);
            this.addCheatForm.reset();
            this.toast.setMessage('item added successfully.', 'success');
            this.commonService.notifyOther({option: 'onSubmit', value: 'Add component'});
        },
        error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```