# How to reload data in list after successful create?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am creating a simple CRUD app with ionic and angular. I am able to perform all CRUD functions. My problem now is that when I add new object into the database, I do not know how to reload the list. I created an add button(on the view data page) to open a create page, when the adding is complete I navigate back the view data page but the list would not be updated.

I have tried to include the function to load data into a list variable in NgOnInit or Constructor but that did not work either.

I have also tried to use an event emitter to call the GetAnime function from the list-view page (after I created a new entry) but I could not get that to work either.

Here is my code for the view-data page .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Anime } from "src/app/Classes/anime";
import { DataServiceService } from "src/app/Services/data-service.service";
import {EventEmitterService} from '../../Services/event-emitter.service';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

import {ModalPage} from '../modal/modal.page';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: "app-anime",
  templateUrl: "./anime.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./anime.page.scss"],
})
export class AnimePage implements OnInit {

  AnimeArray: Anime[] = [];
  // CurrentAnime : Anime;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataServiceService,
    private router: Router,
    public modalController: ModalController,
    private eventEmitterService: EventEmitterService,
  ) 
  {

    this.GetAnime();

  } //Constructor

  ngOnInit() {

    if (this.eventEmitterService.subsVar==undefined) {    
      this.eventEmitterService.subsVar = this.eventEmitterService.    
      CallGetAnime.subscribe((name:string) => {    
        this.firstFunction();    
      });    
    } 

  } //ngOnInit



  CreateAnime(){
    this.router.navigate(['/anime/create-anime']);
  }

  GetAnime(): void {

    this.dataService.GetAnime().subscribe((data) =>

      data.forEach((element) => {
        var anime = new Anime();
        anime.AnimeID = element.AnimeID;
        anime.AnimeName = element.AnimeName;
        anime.Anime_Description = element.Anime_Description;
        this.AnimeArray.push(anime);
      })//For each

    );//Subscribe

  } // Get Anime

  async ItemClick(ItemID : number){

    var CurrentAnime = this.AnimeArray.find(ca => ca.AnimeID == ItemID);

    const modal = await this.modalController.create({

      component : ModalPage,
      componentProps : {

        'CurrentAnime' : CurrentAnime,
        'ModalTitle' : 'Manage Anime'

      }

    });
    await modal.present();

    modal.onDidDismiss().then( (data : any) => {

      try {
        if(data.data.Delete == true)
        {
          this.dataService.DeleteAnime(data.data.ID)
          .subscribe( () => {
            this.AnimeArray = [];
            this.GetAnime();
          });
        }//if
      }//try 
      catch (error) {

      }

    })

  }// Async Item Click

} //Export
```

and here is the code for the create page .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { DataServiceService } from "src/app/Services/data-service.service";
import {EventEmitterService} from '../../../Services/event-emitter.service';
import { Anime } from "src/app/Classes/anime";
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
// import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-anime',
  templateUrl: './create-anime.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-anime.page.scss'],
})
export class CreateAnimePage implements OnInit {

  private CreateAnimeForm: FormGroup;
  private ErrorMessage: string;
  public message : string;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataServiceService,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private eventEmitterService: EventEmitterService
  ){

    this.CreateAnimeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      AnimeName: ["", Validators.required],
      Anime_Description: ["", Validators.required],
    });

  }//Constructor

  CreateAnime(AnimeForm : FormBuilder){

    const anime = AnimeForm.value;

    this.dataService.AddAnime(anime).subscribe(() => {

      this.message = 'Anime has been saved successfully';
      //this.CreateAnimeForm.reset();

      // this.events.publish('functionCall:LoadAnimeData');
      this.eventEmitterService.CallGetAnime;

  });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

p.s All Cruding works, it is just a matter of updating my list after I have added or edited the data. I assume what will work to solve my adding problem will also be the same for editing.
I am using ionic 6.2.2 and angular 9

Comment: Did you try adding a breakpoint to see if your service is being called?

Comment: @maury844 The service is being called as data is definitely being added to the database.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I meant the "getAll" that should be called after the add/edit, my guess of what's happening is that your `viewData` component is not being destroyed for whatever reason and therefore when you go back to it after the process, it is not created again, never calling your service to get the new data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer. i used this post linked below to solve the problem I was having.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47068263/12765810

p.s Using `import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject' did not` so i used 
`import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';` instead. And, adding `private subscription: Subscription;` to the constructor gave me an error so I added it above the constructor as a variable instead.